# Why are silicon and germanium used as semiconductors but not other metalloids?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, conductivity, semiconductors

The semiconductor materials are either elementary such as silicon and germanium or compound such as gallium arsenide. Silicon is the most used semiconductor for discrete devices and integrated circuits.

However, other metalloids like antimony and tellurium are not used as semiconductors. Is it because they are too expensive to extract or is there another reason for this?

Comment: Astatine is highly radioactive and unstable, most stable isotope half life about 8hrs. Not a desirable characteristic for a semiconductor

Comment: It's not important if sth is metalloid, important is its bandgap.

Comment: Alright, Astatine is out of the picture, but what about the others? @Waylander

Comment: The ones you mention aren’t semiconductors. Carbon is a wide band gap semiconductor, with limited doping options. Tin and lead are semi metals and metals. Not much else to say...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement, "metalloids like [a]ntimony and [t]ellurium are not used as semiconductors", is untrue:

- [Tellurium thin-film transistors](http://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.98054) have been fabricated.
- [Bismuth nanowires](https://ir.canterbury.ac.nz/handle/10092/5010) have been used as electronic gates.
- Carbon, in both [diamond](https://phys.org/news/2017-05-engaging-diamond-next-era-transistors.html) and [graphene](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2017/06/170613145144.htm) allotropes, is used.
- Phosphorus, in the form [phosphorene](https://spectrum.ieee.org/semiconductors/materials/is-black-phosphorus-the-new-graphene), structurally similar to graphene, has been used as a semiconducting photodetector.

That said, there are various reasons why these semiconductors have not replaced silicon, which is plentiful, usable to beyond 400 K, resistant to degradation by air, and has an established fabrication technology, for the majority of electronic uses. GaAs, GaN, SiC and other semiconducting compounds are being used increasingly, though, for high-speed electronics, high-temperature devices and lasers.

See the [Wikipedia list of semiconducting elements and compounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_semiconductor_materials)... it's longer than you might expect.

Comment: While bismuth telluride is indeed used in thermoelectrics, it is a compound. Neither Bi nor Te is itself a semiconductor (like neither Ga nor As are, individually, semiconductors).

Comment: A recent paper on the thermodynamics of the Bi-Te system is https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0364591617301219?via%3Dihub - three line compounds and a broad phase field in addition to the elements.

Comment: Te-Bi, as @JonCuster states, is not a single element. However, various literature cites it as either an alloy or an intermetallic compound of definite proportions. In either case, it shouldn't be in the answer and has been removed.  BTW, Bi and Te *can* be used for semiconductor devices.

Comment: What about other elements in the `C Si Ge` priodic table column, like `Sn Pb`? I've seen no usage of such elements as semi-conductors. Are there some?

Comment: AFAIK, they conduct *too* well to be used as semiconductor (though they're superconductors), but *compounds* such as PbS and PbSe are used in IR photodetectors. https://www.lasercomponents.com/de-en/ir-components/ir-detectors/pbs-and-pbse-detectors/, as well as Sn compunds: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/advs.201900751